# Division with Gaussian integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If we are given $A = 7 - 3i, B = 4 + 3i$ and suppose we need to find Gaussian integers $Q, R$ such that $A = QB + R$ with $N(R) < N(B)$ and $N(a + bi) = a^2 + b^2$.

OK, so I did the division normally the same way as we do in complex numbers and got $\frac{A}{B} = \frac{19}{25} - \frac{33}{25}i$ now I rounded up the $\frac{19}{25}$ to 1 and I also rounded up $\frac{-33}{25}i$ to $-i$ and so $Q = 1 - i$ and then I got $R = -2i$ which indeed is a Gaussian integer and $N(R) < N(B)$ is satisfied.

However those are not unique $(Q, R)$; my question is how many different $Q, R$ can we get? I assume it is 4, because we can round (up, up), (down, down), (up, down), (down, up). Is that true?

Comment: Draw a picture! The four possible $R$ differ from each other by $\pm B$ or $\pm iB$. Not all of them have norms $<N(B)$. But for the purposes of Euclid' algorithm it suffices that at least one of them does. Mind you, even in the case of rational integers you often have two choices (differing by $B$). The positive one is conventionally chosen, but in the Gaussian case the remainder with non-negative real+imaginary parts may be too large. So we use another one in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have `up to` 4 $Q$, and hence 4 $(Q,R)$. The Gaussian integers constitute a `lattice` and  $Q$ is one of the 4 four points of the lattice nearest to $\frac A B$ (which belongs to the square whose vertices are these 4 points). Moreover the condition $N(R)<N(B)$ translates to $N(A/B-Q)<1$.

In the present case, the solution $Q=2i$ doesn't satisfy $N(A/B-Q)<1$. So you have only 3 possibilities:

- $Q=-i,\enspace R=4+i$,
- $Q=1-i,\enspace  R=-2i$,
- $Q=2-i, \enspace R=-3+3i$.

Comment: A genius answer!

Comment: $\frac{A}{B} = \frac{19}{25} - \frac{33}{25}i \approx 0.76 - 1.32i$, so the closest points on the `lattice` $1-i$, $1-2i$, $-i$, and $-2i$ with corresponding remainders $-2i$, $-3+2i$, $4+1i$, and $1+5i$, where the last point doesn't satisfy $N(A/B-Q)<1$